# How to close the empty tkinter window that pops up when I run my code

Tags: python, tkinter, window

I am trying to create a tkinter gui that performs a certain calculation. I create a window to ask for input to do the calculations. However, each time I run my code 2 windows pop up instead of one. Is there a way to automatically close the blank window when I run my code such that the user would only see the window that asks for input.

For simplicity I changed all buttons to close the applications.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import tkinter.messagebox
import blpapi
import pdblp
con = pdblp.BCon(timeout=5000)
con.start()

s= ttk.Style()
s.theme_use('xpnative')


root =tk.Tk()

root.title("Vega Requirement Application")
root.geometry("600x400")

ticker_var= tk.StringVar()
volume_var= tk.StringVar()

def close():
    root.destroy()

def clear_all():
    root.destroy()

def vega_calculation():  
    root.destroy()

ticker_label = ttk.Label(root, text='Bloomberg Ticker:',font=('calibre',10,'normal'))
ticker_entry = ttk.Entry(root, textvariable = ticker_var,font=('calibre',10,'normal'))
volume_label = ttk.Label(root, text='Volume:',font=('calibre',10,'normal'))
volume_entry = ttk.Entry(root, textvariable = volume_var,font=('calibre',10,'normal'))

run_btn = ttk.Button(root, text = 'Calculate', command = vega_calculation, width = 13)
close_btn = ttk.Button(root, text= 'Close App', command = close, width =13)
clear_btn = ttk.Button(root, text= 'Clear table', command = clear_all, width=13)



ticker_label.grid(row=0,column=0)
ticker_entry.grid(row=0,column=1)
volume_label.grid(row=1,column=0)
volume_entry.grid(row=1,column=1)
run_btn.grid(row=0,column=2)
close_btn.grid(row=1, column=2)
clear_btn.grid(row=0, column =4)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following two lines will create an instance of `Tk()` because there is no instance of `Tk()` when they are executed:

```
s = ttk.Style()  # create an instance of Tk() if there is none
s.theme_use('xpnative')
```

Move the two lines to after `root = tk.Tk()` so that it uses the already created instance of `Tk()`:

```
root = tk.Tk()

s = ttk.Style()  # use existing instance of Tk(), root
s.theme_use('xpnative')
```